# remove cim instance powershell scrip ( removing profiles for server the correct way ) question

Tags: powershell, profile, remote-desktop, user-profile

I'm using this script to remove corrupted profiles from my RD servers the correct way. I'm wondering if I can make the script ask for the profile name to cleanup instead of typing it in the script manually.

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName servername1, servername2, servername3 -Class Win32_UserProfile | 
Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq 'profilenametocleanup' } | 
Remove-CimInstance
```

The script works well and also removes corrupted registry items. I want our Servicedesk to use it so it would be great to make this more amateur friendly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Absoutely! You just need to replace the variable value `'profilenametocleanup'` with a variable reference!

Variables in PowerShell are defined and assigned like this:

```
$username = "Some value or expression goes here"
```

To prompt the user to input a string value, we can use the `Read-Host` cmdlet:

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the username of the profile to remove!"
```

Then, in the existing pipeline:

```
# replace the 'profiletocleanup' value with our variable instead
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName servername1, servername2, servername3 -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('')[-1] -eq $username } | Remove-CimInstance
```

If you might want to reuse this pipeline in a different script at a later point in time, it might be a good idea to rewrite it as a function:

```
function Remove-RemoteUserProfile
{
  param(
    [string]$Username,
    [string[]]$ComputerName = @('servername1', 'servername2', 'servername3')
  )

  Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('')[-1] -eq $Username } | Remove-CimInstance
}
```

Now you can target any user or set of remote servers with the same command:

```bsh
# Will remove user profile for user jdoe on servername1 through 3
Remove-RemoteUserProfile -User "jdoe"

# Will remove user profile for user jdoe on servername1 and a machine called client5
Remove-RemoteUserProfile -User "bob" -ComputerName servername1,client5

# In this example we prompt the user for the username before calling the function:
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the username of the profile to remove!"
Remove-RemoteUserProfile -User $username -ComputerName someOtherComputer123
```

Comment: One more question: Mathias R. Jessen.

How do i edit the script so it prompts for a username without calling the procedure?

Is it like this:

Get-CimInstance -ComputerName servername1, servername2, servername3 -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('')[-1] -eq $username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the username of the profile to remove!" } | Remove-CimInstance

Comment: @LEVD You need to wrap `Read-Host` in an expression to use it inline like that: `{$something -eq (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter username")}` (notice the parentheses around the `Read-Host` invocation)

Answer (score 0):

The localpath won't always match exactly the username.  Using the sid is more reliable.  In fact, that object is indexed by the sid.

```
$user = 'admin'
$sid = Get-LocalUser $user | foreach { $_.sid.value }
get-wmiobject win32_userprofile | where sid -eq $sid | Remove-WmiObject -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Remove-WmiObject" on target
"\\COMP001\root\cimv2:Win32_UserProfile.SID="S-2-6-31-4961843708-2576926490-3901110831-1002""
```